# How to give one ID to Set of web parts in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, development, javascript, web-part

I am trying to show/ hide set of web parts on click. I already wrote the coding and I can hide/show web parts one by one on click and the reason is that each web part has unique Id.
Now I am facing with problem  because I cannot hide 6 web part together on click and show 6 others.
I tried to add different  to a wiki page in SharePoint. so I can add 6 web part to each of them and then I have one id for each set, but it didn't work!
If someone can help me how to reach "one" ID for set of web parts in SharePoint I would appreciate.

This is my JavaScript coding for each web part and it works well but too long!:

```
function showhideReport(){
 var div =document.getElementById('WebPartWPQ9')
 div.style.display=(div.style.display=="none") ? "block" : "none";
 if(document.getElementById('WebPartWPQ3').style.display=="block")
 document.getElementById('WebPartWPQ3').style.display="none";
 if(document.getElementById('WebPartWPQ10').style.display=="block")
 document.getElementById('WebPartWPQ10').style.display="none";
 if(document.getElementById('WebPartWPQ4').style.display=="block")
 document.getElementById('WebPartWPQ4').style.display="none";
 if(document.getElementById('WebPartWPQ5').style.display=="block")
 document.getElementById('WebPartWPQ5').style.display="none";
 if(document.getElementById('WebPartWPQ13').style.display=="block")
 document.getElementById('WebPartWPQ13').style.display="none";

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tnx, I had some fun with your question, applying an OOP approach

Paste as [snippet in Chrome Controls](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/snippets/?hl=en):

```
function DIVManager( selector , numbers){
    var manager=this;
    function DIV(element){
        var div=this;
        div.state=element.style.display!=='none';
        div.style=function(key,value){
            element.style[key]=value;
            div.state=element.style.display!=='none';
        }
        div.show = div.style.bind(this,'display','block')
        div.hide = div.style.bind(this,'display','none')
        div.toggle=function(){
            div.state ? div.hide() : div.show();
            div.state=!div.state;
        }
    }
    manager.divs=[];
    manager.numbers=[];
    document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(function(element,nr){
        manager.numbers.push(nr);
        manager.divs.push(new DIV(element));
    });
    function action (){
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        if(args.lenght===1)args=manager.numbers;
        manager.divs.forEach(function(element,nr){
            console.log(nr,element);
            if(args.indexOf(nr)>-1) element[args[0]]();
        });
    }
    manager.show=action.bind(this,'show');
    manager.hide=action.bind(this,'hide');
    manager.toggle=action.bind(this,'toggle');
}
var wpM=new DIVManager("div[webpartid]");
wpM.hide(1,3,5);
wpM.toggle(1);
var searchBox=wpM.divs[0];
searchBox.style('zoom',3);
searchBox.style('backgroundColor','pink');
searchBox.style('opacity',.7);
var rotation=0;
window.setInterval(function(){
      searchBox.style( 'transform',String.format("rotate({0}deg)",rotation++ ));
}, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! I am happy if it was interesting for you! I hope to learn coding such as yours! it is very useful in SharePoint!

Answer (score 4):

Address the web parts by giving them a common class and then use the following:

```
document.getElementsByClassName
```

Instead of

```
document.getElementById
```

Comment: How do I add a custom class name to web parts? I can't seem to find an answer to this anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery's starts-with selector:

```
jQuery( "[attribute^='value']" )
```

i.e. to hide / unhide webparts:

```
jQuery( "[id^='WebPartWPQ']" ).each(function() {
  jQuery(this).toggle();
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: Thanks it works for each web part. do you know how can I have one ID from 6 web part? how can I put them in one div so I can do same coding as you said? just like something that BellZBob said above?

Comment: You can use "div[id^='WebPartWPQ']" as a selector and it will not matter where on the page they are, it will just get every div with an ID starting with WebPartWPQ

Answer (score 0):

Please do f12 in browser and check your webpart id. It will add prefix automatically like "MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3". Please pass webpart id with prefix in javascript and test it again.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I already did it. My problem is to have one ID from 6 web part which got solve with answers above!